# CORS error when calling a Firebase function

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, cors, google-cloud-functions

I am using Google Cloud Functions and I am getting an error related to CORS. I have made a simple function but it's not working because I keep getting the same error over and over again. I have tried almost everything but nothing is working.

[image]

Here is the code I am using:

```
const cors = require('cors')({origin: true});
exports.sample = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    cors(req, res, () => {
        res.send('Passed.');
    });
});
```

I have used this and other things too people recommended. I tried adding headers too - but nothing worked.

Comment: Welcome to SO. What exactly have you tried to solve your problem? According to the error message you're missing a specific header.  Without having read it, you may find some information [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/CORSMissingAllowOrigin).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add the header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` in the response from the Google Cloud Function (GCF).

```
def cloud_function(request):
    response = 'what you expect to return from the GCF'
    http_code = 200
    headers = {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
    }

    return response, http_code, headers
```

Notice the header added on the return from the Cloud Function. If you are forced to return more CORS headers you can add them to the `headers` variable (or if you want to return other headers for any other reason). For example:

```
headers = {
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': '*',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Authorization',
    'Access-Control-Max-Age': '3600',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': 'true'
}
```

Answer (score -1):

`https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/YOUR-URL`.
You can use this proxy to bypass the cors issue if it's not for any production use.

OR

You can use `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` in header while hitting the link.

Comment: I tried using the Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * in the header but it did not work. I even tried the following, but still got the error.                                                                   
const cors = require('cors')({origin: true});
exports.sample = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  cors(req, res, () => {
    res.send('Passed.');
  });
});

Comment: You should try with the proxy url.

Comment: const cors = require('cors')({origin: true}); It should have worked for you

Comment: https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/.     Paste this Url before your actual URL